# Lower body exercises that would complement my cycling

Tags: exercise, workout, bicycling, lower-body-strength

I commute by bike and go to the gym two or three times each week. At the gym, I usually do upper body workouts, since I already cycle a lot. Not all my lower body muscles are exercised when I cycle.

Can you recommend me good lower body exercises that would complement my cycling routine? With explanation, please. I'd like to know which muscles I'd have to focus.

I want recommendations based in a health standpoint, not to increase my biking performance.

Comment: Which muscles do you think are not worked by biking?

Comment: If you search google using "complementary exercises to cycling or lower body workout to cycling" key words you will have many good  web pages that you get benefit from

Comment: @bantandor: the internet is full of contradictory information. One of the aims of the StackExchange sites is to give a definitive answer to some common questions. I believe that my question is reasonably general that it deserves a good answer. BTW, almost all the references are about improving your cycling performance, I want to improve my overall health.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNl9USmMqeM

Comment: @never: I just wanted to help you with the keywords in case you missed them.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much anyone who doesn't regularly lift weights at a **intermediate level** should be focusing on doing basic compound lifts in the gym. These lifts will give your entire body a workout so that you can develop all your muscle groups.

I would recommend either Starting Strength by Rippletoe or 5x5 Stronglifts by Mehdi. The documentation on each of these is vast and positive.

For lower body:

- Deadlifts
- Squats

For above the waist:

- Overhead Press
- Bent over row
- Benchpress

(* note: I classify Intermediate level as: you train 4-6 days a week in the gym and have graduated off a starter program like 5x5 Stronglifts or Starting Strength)

Comment: ... kettlebells *are* free weights. I also don't agree with your definition of what intermediate level is. You also imply that only beginners benefit from basic compound lifts, which is completely not true. You may also want to avoid abbreviations as people who are less familiar with the terminology may not know what you mean.

Comment: The comment about kettlebells was just a jibe at their popularity and misuse. Ill adjust my comment as I imply that everyone at all levels can benefit from compound lifts but for those that lift competitively (advanced and high intermediate) focusing on hypertrophy through isolation is commonly accepted as sensible. I'll adjust the abbreviations too.